# Amount of passed parameters to functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

JavaScript is a revelation to me. I thought it would be like another sort of classical languages like C#, Java, etc. But it didn't. "Dynamic world" is tough and unpredictable. I was astonished when I read that functions can receive as many parameters as you desire. Without any error! I don't like it at all. I want more "staticness", I want some sort of compile-time errors!

My question is: am I need to worry about that? Is it a good practice to throw an exception if a quantity of passed parameters are more than a particular function expects?

```
function foo(one, two, three)
{
    // Is it good?
    if(arguments.length > arguments.callee.length)
        throw new Error("Wrong quantity of arguments in " + arguments.callee.name + "()");

    /* Stuff */
}

foo(1, 2, 3, 4); // -> Error
foo(1, 2, 3);    // -> OK
```

Should I be concerned about it at all?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What exactly are you worried about that you think this approach would solve?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably should not be concerned.  There is no blanket rule on how to handle errors like this.  It depends entirely upon the type of error and the type of situation.  In some cases, where it's a serious programming error and there is no way to proceed (like insufficient arguments to perform the desired function), it may make sense to throw an exception or return an error from the function.  But, in other cases, an extra argument can just be safely ignored and you can continue on your merry way as if that argument was never passed.

As you get used to javascript, you will come to understand that many function arguments can be optional and a single function may be correctly called with zero, one, two or three or even N arguments and the code in the function can adapt appropriately.  This actually allows you to do things that are not as easy to do in more "static" languages.  It is even possible to adapt to the type of the arguments and do something appropriately based on the type of the argument.  While this may sound like heresy to someone that only has experience in hard-typed languages, it can actually be extremely useful.

As you maintain a body of code over time, you will also come to find that it's nice to be able to add an argument to the definition of a function, add code to that function that defaults it to a reasonable value if it isn't passed and NOT have to change any of the prior code that was using that function, yet a few new places that need that new argument can start using it immediately.  Rather then grepping through the entire codebase to fix up every caller of that function, you can just make one change in one file and immediately start using a new argument to the function without changing all the other callers.  This is enormously useful.

---

So, in more direct answer to your question, an extra argument passed to a function is never a serious error in javascript.  Your code could just ignore it and proceed.  If you want to alert the developer who wrote that code that an unexpected argument was passed, you can notify them somehow (perhaps some warning text on the debug console) in the "debug" version of your function/library, but I see no reason why you should stop execution in the "production" version of your function/library when you can proceed without any harm.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to worry about this.  If you pass too many arguments, the function will just ignore it.  You should only throw an error if there are *too few* arguments.  In that case, the function might not be able to run.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that the number of arguments aren't important (and won't cause a problem so long as you type-check the arguments you're getting before you use them), since an unused, uncalled, argument won't *do anything*, if you're particularly concerned you could just create a subset of the passed-arguments and access that object internally:

```
function test(arg1, arg2, arg3) {
    var slice = Array.prototype.slice,
        subset = slice.call(arguments, 0, 3); // depending on how many arguments you want
}
```

Of course this means that you've now got to recover the parameters from the `args` object, and since surplus arguments seem to be perfectly safe this seems pointless. But it is still an option.

Albeit unnecessary.